# SQL Find id-s where value of column equals a value on specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I work with the following table:

```
ID   LETTER    VALUE

1       A      NON-VALID   
1       B      VALID 
1       C      VALID
1       D      VALID
2       A      NON-VALID
2       B      VALID
2       C      NON-VALID
2       D      VALID
```

So, what I want is simple, but I haven't found something similar or figured it out by myself.

I want to take the IDs that have let's say the value VALID in all the letters I will define.For example, if I want to have valid values on Bs and Cs, I want my data set to return ID 1.

Silly example:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM table 
WHERE VALUE=VALID IN EVERY ROW WHERE LETTER BETWEEN 'B' AND 'C'
```

Comment: You might want to use an [`AND`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) instead of "IN EVERY ROW WHERE"

Comment: That will return also the row 2 B VALID...

Comment: Then also use a DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
select id
from t
where letter in ('B', 'C') and value = 'Valid'
group by id
having count(distinct letter) = 2;  -- "2" is the number of letters in your list
```

Comment: What if I don't know a priori the number of letters I want to examine?

Comment: @JAMAICA . . . If you know the list, then you know the number.